# Weird VS++ syntax errors in header file? (SDL2 Related)

Tags: c++

So I've recently tried to clean up my code in an attempt to make it easier on myself (and others if needed).

Now, It could be due to the fact that I'm kinda new to the whole C++ thing (though, I've got a few more years experience with Java). But I've heard (more like read) that it's a bad idea to include headers in your header files as it'll bog the rest of your program down and make things a headache (and true to this, I've had a few problems where I only need to include one header within a ".cpp" file and it has all the includes I need (apparently)).

So I decided to do the following to my headers:

```
#pragma once

class Game {
(...)
public:
    SDL_Window* getPrimaryWindow(void) const;
    SDL_Renderer* getPrimaryRenderer(void) const;
    SDL_Surface* getPrimarySurface(void) const;
(...)
private:
    SDL_Window* mp_primaryWindow = 0;
    SDL_Renderer* mp_primaryRenderer = 0;
    SDL_Surface* mp_primarySurface = 0;
};
```

So, I've not included any headers in my ".hpp" file but instead are in my ".cpp" file. Now, No intellisense errors get triggered in either of the files... "All good" I think. Hover over each variable and the following shows:

```
SDL_Window *Game::mp_primaryWindow
```

And if I hover over the type:

```
struct SDL_Window
*\brief The Type used to identify a window
(...)
```

Same goes for SDL_Renderer and SDL_Surface... All good.

Now, I try to build the project... This is where it all goes to hell and pukes the following errors at me:

```
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note C++
does not support default-int
```

So, no good at all then. But if I add `#include <SDL.h>` to the top, it compiles and builds fine.

Could someone explain what is happening, why it's happening and if I have to go back through my code and put all the includes back into my headers?

Comment: I am not totally sure why that is happening but I believe you that to have to include the headers in the header file since you have SDL structures as return values (how would the compiler know about them?). Probably something wrong with intellisense.

Comment: But wouldn't that start bogging the rest of my project out? :L

What I mean by that is, the other source files I include Game in would pick up the SDL.h file?

Comment: Why would it? You are using #pragma once

Comment: When I re-include SDL.h into Game.hpp, and then comment out the SDL.h in another source file, errors do not appear?

Comment: It should not take too much effort to try it out right? Try it and write here if something goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should avoid including headers in your headers when you don't need to include them.  If you use a non built in type in a header though, you either need to include the header that defines that type (include it in that header), or you need to forward declare that type.  Forward declarations often look like this, although they can vary depending on the type of what you are forward declaring: "class CWindow;" and go at the top of the file.  Forward declarations only work if you have pointers or references to the type, but not actual objects in the class, or actual objects being passed as a parameter to functions in the header.

Note that including headers in headers is mostly just bad for compilation times.  If your program is not compiling too slowly, don't stress - just include headers in your headers and everything will be fine.

There is actually a case where you SHOULD include headers in your headers by the way.  Basically if you use some class "CSomeClass" in your header, you could require that the CPP files that include your header also include "CSomeClass.h" before your header, but that puts extra burden on people using your class.  Your header file should be self contained and should either include the headers for all types it needs, or should forward declare them.

Hope that helps! Java and C++ are pretty different in day to day usage (:

Comment: i prefer to include header files in the header because it gives a quick overview of the class members and the included classes/functions (it also makes it more sorted because you include all files at the same place). I have never noticed any big difference in compile time.

Comment: If you work on a large project where you have ~50 projects each with about a hundred files, that takes 5 minutes to clean build with a distributed build system, and a full 5 minutes to link (non distributed linking of course!), forward declarations are amazing and really help build times.  For smaller projects, like you say, it usually doesn't even matter at all (:

Comment: I just started getting worried that it'd all start bogging itself down. Now that I've sorted (or at least I think I have) the way I'll be doing things, it should be less "global" per sae.